# MS-Access to SQL Server 2000 problem with datetime

Tags: sql, ms-access, import, sql-server-2000

I'm trying to transfer some data from Access to SQL Server 2000 (there are no other way to do this sadly), I'm using [Access to mssql](http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2s/info.php) to do the job. The program fails everytime it finds a datetime in this fashion:

```
03/07/2009 10.17.00
```

While it imports date like this:

```
29/12/2008
```

I don't understand where this problem come from so I ask you for your help.

Thank you very much.

Comment: How much data are you trying to transfer? Is it to a new table or an existing table? Have you considered http://dev.mysql.com/doc/migration-toolkit/en/index.html or ODBC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx) might come in handy. Never worked with that program (always used DTS for such tasks), so I don't know its specs to tell you more.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it doesn't liek the time having a `.` delimiter - can you run an update to change `.` to `:`, or change the select on the table to replace while selecting?

Answer (score 0):

How do you know that the year has a valid century portion, that is 19 or 20, in all the records?    There could be some dates in the table with a century that is 09 or whatever folks can manage to enter without noticing.  Especially if the default data format of thier system only has a two digit year?

The default SQL Server small date/time field specification in SQL Server doesn't allow for dates  outside 1900-01-01 through 2079-06-06